# Beautiful Soup find all occurrences of tag between other tags for html page

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a webpage that has the following tags:

```
('span', {'class' : 'block-title'})
('div', {'class' : 'object-title'})
('span', {'class' : 'data-value'})
```

I can loop through the page using a for loop and it extracts the data I need using the below

```
for a in soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'block-title'}):
print a

for b in soup.find_all('div', {'class' : 'object-title'})
print b 

for c in soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'data-value'})
print c
```

The issue I have is it gives me them in three separate lists I need the code to find the first occurrence of block-title then all the occurrences of either object-title and data-value in order, followed by the next block-title etc I think this may be possible with find next or find sibling but was looking for some help/advice

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use the results from your first `find_all()` call and find all relevant tags within them by passing a list to the next `find_all()` call. Something like this:

```
for a in soup.find_all('span', {'class' : 'block-title'}):
    print a
    for b in print a.find_all(['div', 'span'], {'class' : ['object-title', 'data-value']}):
        print b
```